# Desktop Application Dependency Injection with Unity

Tags: c#, winforms, dependency-injection, unity-container

I've used unity with MVC Web App.
and in MVC we there is app_start method.
and we use

```
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
```

and this send the parameters to the Controller Constructor.
now i am trying to find how to implement this pattern to DesktopApplication.

u guys know that we use new Form1().Show(); //bla bla foo
and when i create a new form is it possible to do when i created a new instance of type of System.Windows.Forms it automatically send the parameters to the constructor.

Sorry for my language.
now i am using something like this and asking if it's a better solution:

```
public partial class frm_FirmaSecimi : XtraForm
{
    private IFirmaService _firmaService;

    public frm_FirmaSecimi()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _firmaService = UnityConfig.Container.Resolve<IFirmaService>();
    }
}
```

is there a way to turn this in to:

```
public partial class frm_FirmaSecimi : XtraForm
{
    private IFirmaService _firmaService;

    public frm_FirmaSecimi(IFirmaService firmaService)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _firmaService = firmaService;
    }
}
```

this is a DevExpress Form by the way.
Thanx for answers.

Comment: What's exactly your question? Your second code sample uses the dependency injection approach which is all good. What is your challenge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try introducing interfaces for your forms, then use this on each form:

```
public class FormMain : IFormMain
{
    ISubForm _subForm;

    public FormMain(ISubForm subForm) 
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _subForm = subForm;
    }

    ...

}
```

Now, on program start, create the Unity container, and resolve your `IFormMain` dependency:

```
private static void Main()
{
    var container = BuildContainer();
    Application.Run(container.Resolve<IFormMain>());
}

public static IUnityContainer BuildContainer()
{
    var currentContainer = new UnityContainer() ;
    currentContainer.RegisterType<IFormMain, FormMain>();
    // note: registering types could be moved off to app config if you want as well
    return currentContainer;
}
```

Obviously your implementation won't look exactly like this, however it should point you in the right direction.

**Disclaimer:** I don't work with WinForms at all, so the above may not be the best solution for app, depending on it's complexity etc..

Also try reading this, it may help: http://foyzulkarim.blogspot.co.nz/2012/09/using-dependency-injection-unity-to.html